# Payload to DynamoDB - weird numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, iot, aws-iot, payload

I am trying to take a payload from an IoT sensor (I can edit the embedded code in the sensor) and put it in a DynamoDB in AWS.

This is what I get:

```
Payload: "{ "state" : { "M" : { "reported" : { "M" : { "Watt" : { "N" : "999" } } }, "SensorNo" : { "N" : "1" } } } }"
```

In the DynamoDB I get proper values written as SensorNo: 1, but Watt is set to 1538330043128.

I have tried to configure them as both Number and String, but with same result.

Any suggestions what might cause this? I want it to write 999 as the Payload say.

Comment: The 1538330043128 numbers looks like an Epoch millisecond timestamp (September 30, 2018 5:54:03 UTC). Is the code that writes to DynamoDB putting the wrong value as the Watt?

Comment: Thank you Tom! You were absolutely correct! It sure was an Epoch timestamp, and the issue was my Hash Key formatting. Now it works! Thanks.